# Google App Script - Using column headers as name in JSON key/value pair

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase

I have the following code, which I am using with the 'FireBaseApp Library Resource' to update FireBase.

```
function writeDataToFirebase() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".......mySheetRef.........");
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();


      var dataToImport = {};
      for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        var EventName = data[i][0];
        var Description = data[i][1];

        dataToImport[EventName] = {
          EventName:EventName,
          Description:Description,
          EmailAddress:data[i][2],
          who:data[i][4],
          client:data[i][5],
          partners:data[i][6],
          EventDate:data[i][7]
        };
      }
      var firebaseUrl = "https://myFireBase.firebaseio.com/";
      var secret = "secret_here";
      var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
      base.setData("", dataToImport);

    }
```

All works perfectly, except ...

To add scalability to the project, I would like to **dynamically** add the Key "Name" from the Row 1 Column headers. So if the column name changes or more columns are added the script wont need to be rewitten each time.

so, instead of hard coding ...

```
EmailAddress:data[i][2],
I would like
"row 1 column header value":data[i][2],
```

I can't seem to make that bit work :-(

Any help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried adding ....

```
    -> var Headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
 Logger.log(Headers);

  var dataToImport = {};

for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var EventName = data[i][0];
  var Description = data[i][1];

  dataToImport[EventName] = {
    EventName:EventName,
    Description:Description,
  -> Headers[2]:data[i][2],
    who:data[i][4],
    client:data[i][5],
    partners:data[i][6],
    EventDate:data[i][7]
  };
}
```

But this creates a "Missing : after property ID. " error !

So I am still looking for a way to capture the value of the column headers dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code might work for you as it does for me, with any columns configuration. You need to assign the uniquecolumn header (unique in the example below)

```
var sheetsid = "your-google-sheet-id-here";
var fbpath = "https://your-app-here.firebaseio.com/fromsheet";
var fbsecret = "your-secret-here";
function sheet2FB() {
  var sheetname = "Data";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetsid).getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var uniquecolumn = "unique";
  var objectsarray = xsLibSheets.getRows(sheet);
  var fbready = objectsarray.reduce(function(p,v){ p[v[uniquecolumn]] = v; return p; }, {});
  var fb = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(fbpath, fbsecret);
  fb.setData("", fbready);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(fbready,null,2));
  return;
}
```

The function getRows() get the data from a sheet as a json objects array using the headers as keys.
You can find the library code [on this link](https://script.google.com/d/1nu9aiG3NXt0gaQ5DpK-Lc7KLB8yrICxjgFM04rFg8lfx5M0C3TKKGG5p/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: FABULOUS ! Thank you @Fausto. This works just the way I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The code has a new variable, `row1_Col2_HdrVal` that always gets data from index zero, which will be row one, IF you get the range with `getDataRange()`.

```
var dataToImport = {},
    row1_Col2_HdrVal = data[0][2],
    innerObject = {};

for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
  var innerKeyName = data[i][0];

  var j=0;
  for (j=0;j<length;j+=1) {
    innerObject[innerKeyName] = data[i][j];
  };

  dataToImport[EventName] = innerObject;
}
```

I don't know if this is what you need.  If not, give feedback in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @sandy-good. <br/>
I had tried something like this, but the code simply writes out "row1_Col2_HdrVal" as the key Name not the content of the variable !


I also need this to be able to capture ALL the headers in row 1, not just the value in cell [0][2].

Comment: Okay.  I think you'll need an inner loop, then put the inner object into the outer object.  I changed the code.  The code is probably totally useless, but maybe it will give you an idea.

Comment: Cheers Sandy, I will have a play with your suggestion.